# Numbers, arrays and signs

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I can't find a way to store Strings into a array. I got different examples in which the array contain names or numbers, but i want something like: String v1 = "+31", String v2 = "-65", String v3="58"  I want to store those values in an array as integers, and then check their signs (+ or - ) to add, and subtract.

Comment: If you want to store the values as integers, you should be using an `int[]` rather than a `String[]`... it's not really clear what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Your requirement isn't clear. Do you want to store an array of string values or an array of integer values? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Trying to convert string values to integer values? Something else?

Comment: First read the strings, then make a loop to store them in an array as integers, Then use those integers to add and substract.

Answer (score 2):

Use something like

```
myArray[0] = Integer.parseInt(yourString);
```

When adding a negative number, you will lose numbers. Don't use +60, just use 60. Use -60 for subtraction.

You can add for each member of an array with

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    myInt += myArray[i];
}
```

All together:

```
public class MyClass {

    int[] myNumbers;
    int mathMe = 10; // Things will be done to this number.

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        myArray[0] = Integer.parseInt("60"); // 60 will be added to 10.
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            myInt += myArray[i];
        }

    }

}
```

Read Java tutorials throughly, there are certain tricks you pick up along the way. Looping through arrays is one of them. Programming is hard, and you have to give it everything you got to succeed at it. That's why almost everyone who programs loves it - the only way to get that kind of dedication from a person is to make it a passion. I guess what it boils down to is, Pay attention in class, and learn the perfect keywords for Google. And be patient too. Forums are generally not the first place you go to.